# Shortening a repetitive 1400-line MySQL UNION query using PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysql, union

I have a MYSQL table that is 1275 fields wide.  Each row in the table represents a single class of students, with 17 fields per student, X up to 75 students per class, so 17 X 75 = 1275 fields.

I have devised an SQL UNION query that successfully pulls the students into another table, with each student on a single row.

Now, I want to use this UNION query as part of a PHP program.  I have "imported" the query into PHP as it is.  But, isn't there a way to use PHP to shorten the SQL query?  Shamelessly, here is my code:

```
    $sql = "
    INSERT INTO $t_mem2
    SELECT localcourse
         , statecourse
         , coursetitle
         , semester
         , section
         , teachercode
         , teachername
         , meetingcode
         , classpop
         , student_id_01 AS student_id
         ,        sex_01 AS sex
         ,        dob_01 AS dob
         ,      grade_01 AS grade
         ,     ethnic_01 AS ethnic
         ,  last_name_01 AS last_name
         , first_name_01 AS first_name
         , $c_sch        AS sch_code
    FROM $t_mem1
    UNION
    SELECT localcourse
         , statecourse
         , coursetitle
         , semester
         , section
         , teachercode
         , teachername
         , meetingcode
         , classpop
         , student_id_02 AS student_id
         ,        sex_02 AS sex
         ,        dob_02 AS dob
         ,      grade_02 AS grade
         ,     ethnic_02 AS ethnic
         ,  last_name_02 AS last_name
         , first_name_02 AS first_name
         , $c_sch        AS sch_code
    FROM $t_mem1
    UNION 
    SELECT localcourse
         , statecourse
         , coursetitle
<...snip..............................>
     , teachername
     , meetingcode
     , classpop
     , student_id_75 AS student_id
     ,        sex_75 AS sex
     ,        dob_75 AS dob
     ,      grade_75 AS grade
     ,     ethnic_75 AS ethnic
     ,  last_name_75 AS last_name
     , first_name_75 AS first_name
     , $c_sch        AS sch_code
  FROM $t_mem1
 ORDER
    BY localcourse
     , statecourse
     , semester
     , section
     , teachername
     , meetingcode
     , last_name
     , first_name" ;
```

Comment: Things would shorten up if you normalize the database.

Comment: You're making your life harder by not using a relational database the way it was intended, namely to maintain data efficiently using relationships between tables.  Look into normalization and save yourself hours of  future headaches.

Comment: But the 1275-column table is a given in this project, not an option.  I did not make the table.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: `I have a MYSQL table that is 1275 fields wide.` My condolences.

Comment: wow! thats just nuts. Demand you normalize the data first then write what ever code goes around it.

Comment: @Everybody: Maybe what he's trying to do right now is to get the data out into a normalized table, eh?  Enough already!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, this query indicates that your database schema is very, very poor.

That aside, yes, you can shorten the query with PHP:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO $t_mem2 ";
for ($i = 1; $i <= 75; $i++) {
    if ($i > 1) {
        $query .= ' UNION ';
    }
    $s = "$i";
    if ($i < 10) {
       $s = '0'.$s;
    }
    $query .= "SELECT localcourse
         , statecourse
         , coursetitle
         , semester
         , section
         , teachercode
         , teachername
         , meetingcode
         , classpop
         , student_id_{$s} AS student_id
         ,        sex_{$s} AS sex
         ,        dob_{$s} AS dob
         ,      grade_{$s} AS grade
         ,     ethnic_{$s} AS ethnic
         ,  last_name_{$s} AS last_name
         , first_name_{$s} AS first_name
         , $c_sch        AS sch_code FROM $t_mem1";
}
$query .= " ORDER
BY localcourse
 , statecourse
 , semester
 , section
 , teachername
 , meetingcode
 , last_name
 , first_name" ;
```

This will "shorten the query" by generating it in PHP code.  If, on the other hand, you're looking to make the query *as it hits the database* shorter, that is also possible; just modify the loop above to start `$query` anew in each iteration, and glom all the results together in one array.  You'll end up with 75 queries made, and PHP will perform the UNION.

Comment: Instead of using an if statement for the `$i < 10` it might be clearer to use `sprintf` or `str_pad` instead. Also, adding everything to an array and using `implode` might make the code even easyer to read :)
+1 btw

Comment: Thank you, Borealid.  That was very fast and I will implement your solution.  This "wide" table is a download from a state government agency.  If you want the kids in a school, this is what you get.  Period. :-)

Comment: @WoLpH: You're right on both counts. My thinking on the first was just that this is so simple you might as well do the easily-readable `$i < 10` block.  I think the reason I didn't use `implode` was because I'd already taken the query from 1400 lines down to 20 :-P.

Comment: Thanks again, Borealid.  Very minor: I changed the position of your "UNION" statement, and added the "FROM $t_mem1" phrase.  Worked like butter!!

Answer (score 2):

Let me be the first to say OMG!

Second, start reading about normalization: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Third: use a loop and replace `01`..`75` with `printf('%02d', $i)`

Answer (score 2):

I call WoLpH's OMG, and I raise a WTF.

To explain a bit more what the others mean by "normalization", you want to have (at least) two tables here: one for courses, one for students (probably also one for teachers). All the fields with a number go into the `students` table, `teachername` and `teachercode` (possibly with a `id`) go into `teachers` table, and everything else goes into the `courses` table, along with some new fields: `teacher_id` (or `teachercode`) and `student_id`, and preferably its own `AUTOINCREMENT`ed `id` as well. Then, when you want to get the results similar to your 70Kb query,  you do this:

```
SELECT C.id AS course_id
     , C.localcourse
     , C.statecourse
     , C.coursetitle
     , C.semester
     , C.section
     , T.teachercode
     , T.teachername
     , C.meetingcode
     , C.classpop
     , C.student_id
     , S.sex
     , S.dob
     , S.grade
     , S.ethnic
     , S.last_name
     , S.first_name
FROM courses C
JOIN students S ON C.student_id = S.id
JOIN teachers T ON C.teacher_id = T.id
```

Also, you probably don't need `classpop`, you can get it with `SELECT COUNT(C.student_id) AS classpop ... GROUP BY C.id`.

Comment: Thank you.  I do need to become more familiar with normalization.  No excuses, except that in my job, I may use a table to get certain data, solve a minor problem, and then I may never use the table again.  So, there is little, if any, permanency in anything I do.